# After change username, the new usarname not display in the login Window

Tags: users, root, home

I to change my username how [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34074/how-do-i-change-my-username) (answer from **Egil*) to say, but the username from the login window not change...

Can Please anyone help me, thanks!

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you want. As I am understanding, you want:

a HOME folder /home/love for your existing user: linux
and it should contain all files and directories of /home/linux

is this correct?

Comment: Yes, I will change my username,  now can do it as here to say    https://askubuntu.com/questions/34074/how-do-i-change-my-username  ( answer from Igil), but the name from log Window no change...

Comment: The display manager likely uses you GECOS fullname rather than the login name - you can change that with the `chfn` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@steeldriver Very Thanks!

I will change my login name from **linux** to **love**, I does it with

```
sudo chfn -f "love" linux
```